# Generate a button with href to route with model binding Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route :
`Route::get('/{domain}/{category}', 'Website\CategoryController@show')->name('website.category.show');`

In `Domain` and `Category` model I have a function that finds them by slug :

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
```

Now I'm trying to generate buttons for each domains category, like that:

```
 <li class="nav-item p-2"><a href="{{route('website.category.show',['domain' => $domain->slug, 'category' => $category->slug])}}" class="btn btn-outline-success">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
```

But it generates me links like `localhost:8000/first-slug`.  The second parameter is missing. Also, if I delete the second parameter from button, like that :

```
 <li class="nav-item p-2"><a href="{{route('website.category.show','domain' => $domain->slug)}}" class="btn btn-outline-success">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
```

it gives me error :

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: website.category.show] [URI: {domain}/{category}].
```

Comment: what do you get when you do {{dump(route('website.category.show',['domain' => $domain->slug, 'category' => $category->slug]))}} ?

Comment: Foreach domain->category it returns link like : 
"http://localhost:8000/slug-of-domain"

Comment: what do you get when you add that code i wrote to your blade?

Comment: That's what I get when I run your code. So, it takes only one parameter, but if I change parameter list from 2 to only 1, it gives me that route requires 2 parameters.

Comment: what about {{dump(route('website.category.show',['domain' => 'test', 'category' =>'test2']))}} ? maybe category is empty of the attribute is null

Comment: You right buddy. Thanks!